# Android emulator gives

Tags: android, react-native, performance, android-studio

```
device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2181 GL error 0x501
2023-08-07 10:12:06.778 13394-13587 emuglGLESv2_enc         com.theartfulmaestro.dim             E  device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2181 GL error 0x501
2023-08-07 10:12:06.779 13394-13587 emuglGLESv2_enc         com.theartfulmaestro.dim             E  device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2181 GL error 0x501
2023-08-07 10:12:06.779 13394-13587 emuglGLESv2_enc         com.theartfulmaestro.dim             E  device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2181 GL error 0x501
2023-08-07 10:12:06.779 13394-13587 emuglGLESv2_enc         com.theartfulmaestro.dim             E  device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2181 GL error 0x501

2023-08-07 10:12:07.568 13394-13587 emuglGLESv2_enc         com.theartfulmaestro.dim             E  GLESv2_enc         com.theartfulmaestro.dim             E  device/generic/goldfish-opengl/system/GLESv2_enc/GL2Encoder.cpp:s_glGetUniformLocation:2181 GL error 0x501
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.